# jsf:The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, intellij-idea

i tried to create a new jsf project, after creating the project i tried to see that the base is correct or not , so i made a `test.xhtml` to check it ,

test.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    >
<h:outputLabel value="yes that's work "/>
</html>
```

and my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but after running , it shows me :

[image]

what can i do to make it to work ?

thank's in advance,

---

i am using intellij idea with tomcat 7.0.50

java version "1.7.0_25"

os: ubuntu

Comment: You said you use test.xhtml and why are you calling localhost:8081/index.jsf. have you tried calling localhost:8081/test.jsf and is not working? Are you sure the view index.xhtml is available?

Comment: really it is `index.xhtml` but i thought that `test.xhtml is better for asking question

Comment: how is your project called, which you created at the beginning? call in your browser http://localhost:8081/<MYPROJECT>/faces/test.jsf

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using a different tag library in your view, xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" instead of xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"? Also as Patrick mentioned you might need to add the context root of your application to the url, which is the project name if it is not explicitly set.

Comment: @Patrick you can't add /faces/ if you don't explicitly set it in the url pattern in the web.xml so he should more likely try localhost:8081/<MYPROJECT>/test.jsf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks all

it does not find the resources ( lib folder) , so i tried to copy the lib folder under `WEB-INF` path , so it works now ,

the another reason to use maven :)